# Handling time series data with same start and end datetime but different vector lengths

Tags: time-series, data-preprocessing, aggregation

I am dealing with time series data with 15 different features from a machine. The thing is that the different feature datasets that have been collected have been done at different frequecies. That is some have been collected every second meanwhile others have been collected every three seconds. The problem that I am facing is that I have columns (each representing a feature) that have the same start and end datetime and their corresponding industry values (such as temperature, pressure, airflow) but they differ in column lengths.

So for example if I have two features and they both have the starting datetime 2021-11-01 12:00:00 and end datetime 2021-11-11 12:00:00 with one being collected every 1 second and another being collected every two seconds. Then one would be of length $10\text{ days}*24\text{ hours}*3600\text{ seconds} $ and the other $10*24*3600/2$. My questions is how I can go about getting them to same length. One way that I thought of would be take the mean of the industry value of two consecutive timesteps in the first feature, then I would get half of the length. Is there a name for this data preprocessing technique?

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't necessarily need to get them to the same length.  That might be part of a possible procedure for addressing your data analysis needs, but perhaps it's superfluous or would even lose information.  What do you want to learn from these data?

Comment: The data will go into a machine learning algorithm that will predict when the machine should be maintained. And my understanding is that most ML algorithms need the different features to have the same length as input.